# Unable to view TextView(uppermost view in LinearLayout) on device even though it is showing in preview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not able to view the `TextView` in device and in emulator but it is there in preview. I am using android studio. I even try to add some other views instead of textView but I am still facing the same problem.

Did I miss something or do I need to make any change in the setting of android studio.

This problem started after I used the `scrollView`.

The code which I am using is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
android:id="@+id/scroll">
<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<!--THE BELOW TEXTVIEW IS NOT VISIBLE ON MY DEVICE BUT IT'S SHOWING IN PREVIEW -->

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Topping"
android:textAllCaps="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Whipped Cream"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chocolate"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="increment"
        android:text="+" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        android:text="-" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="ORDER SUMMARY"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"
    android:text="ORDER" />
```

Comment: Copied and pasted the whole xml to my editor, it's also visible. Ran on my emulator and everything was visible. Android Studio urged me to change the first `LinearLayout`'s `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` and so I did. It worked both ways anyway. Can you show some screenshots please?

Comment: Did you try to scroll up to see if the TextView shows up?

Comment: I have also changed it to wrap_content but no luck their.
I have added **android:layout_marginTop="36dp"** in the TextView and now I can see it .But as per my understanding it should come automatically.I tried this because in preview TextView was there.
I am still clueless why it didn't work without margin_top

Answer (score 1):

I tried checking the layout file .It worked for me as i found some of the end tags missing in the content provided by just adding them it worked .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <!--THE BELOW TEXTVIEW IS NOT VISIBLE ON MY DEVICE BUT IT'S SHOWING IN PREVIEW -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Topping"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Whipped Cream"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chocolate"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:onClick="increment"
                android:text="+" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:onClick="decrement"
                android:text="-" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="ORDER SUMMARY"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="ORDER" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of the textview because the some API default color is white.
Set the textview color as `android:textColor="@color/black"`

Comment: The theme decides whether to show white font on dark background or black font on a bright background. Overriding the text color isn't a good idea in some cases